# Form file upload, adding loading spinner, placement wrong and not removing when completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a loading spinner on an HTML form where I am loading image previews.  The loader works and one is created for each file that is to be uploaded, the issue is that the loaders are always in the top left of the div and only the first loader is removed when the preview generation is completed.

```js
    if( window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader )
    {
      $( '#files' ).on( 'change', function( event )
      {
        var files  = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById( "result" );
        for( var i = 0; i< files.length; i++ )
        {
          var file = files[ i ];
          //Only pics
          if( file.type.match( 'image.*' ) )
          {
              if( this.files[ 0 ].size < 20971520 )
              {    
               // Show the loading gif while it uploads
               var loading       = document.createElement( "div" );
               loading.innerHTML = "<div class='loading'></div>";
               output.insertBefore( loading, null ); 
              // continue;
               var picReader = new FileReader();
               picReader.addEventListener( "load", function( event )
               {
                loading.innerHTML = "";
                  var picFile   = event.target;
                  var div       = document.createElement( "div" );
                  div.innerHTML = '<div class="preview_container"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="'  + picFile.result +  '" alt="Image"></div><div class="image_title">' + file.name + '</div></div>';
                  output.insertBefore( div, null );            
               });
               //Read the image
               $( '#clear, #result' ).show();
               picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
              }
              else
              {
                alert( "Image Size is too big. Maximum size is 20MB." );
                $( this ).val( "" );
              }
          }
          else
          {
           alert( "You can only upload image file." );
           $( this ).val( "" );
        }
        }                               
      });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log( "Your browser does not support File API" );
    }
```

```css
// Image previewer for uploading
.thumbnail{
    height:         100px;
    margin:         10px; 
    float:          left;
}

#clear{
   display:         none;
}
#result {
    border:         4px dotted #cccccc;
    display:         none;
    float:          right;
    margin:         0;
    width:          511px;
}
.preview_container {
  position:         relative;
  // height:          100px;
  float:           left;
  margin:          10px;
  z-index:          1;
}
.thumbnail > img {
  height:          100px;
}
.image_title {
  text-align:        center;
}

$base-line-height:          24px;
$white:                     rgb(255,255,255);
$off-white:                 rgba($white, 0.2);
$spin-duration:             1s;
$pulse-duration:            750ms;

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform:              rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:              rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
    border-radius:          50%;
    width:                  $base-line-height;
    height:                 $base-line-height;
    border:                 .25rem solid $off-white;
    border-top-color:       $white;
    animation:              spin $spin-duration infinite linear;
  &--double {
    border-style:           double;
    border-width:           .5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="files" type="file" name="images[]" multiple/>
<button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
<output id="result" />
```

Here is a fiddle of what I have so far - https://jsfiddle.net/os394n57/

I am looking for help with placing the loading animation where the image preview is going to be and removing the loading animation as the preview is generated for each preview in turn.

Cheers in advance,

Blinky

Comment: Do you know about Font Awesome and other libraries like it? http://fontawesome.io/icon/circle-o-notch/ You can add the fa-spin class and you're done for the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due the asynchronous nature of callbacks , when the `load` fires for the first image your loop is already either over (99%) or on its last iteration so `loading` in all those callbacks would have the same value (final value) so function would wipe only that single loader div ( one for the last image) keeping rest of the loaders as is .You can implement a closure to tackle this issue

```
var picReader = new FileReader();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
picReader.onload = (function(file,loading )
{
    return function myFunc(event){
        loading.innerHTML = "";
        var picFile   = event.target;
        var div       = document.createElement( "div" );
        div.innerHTML = '<div class="preview_container"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="'  + picFile.result +  '"     alt="Image"></div><div     class="image_title">' + file.name + '</div></div>';
        output.insertBefore( div, null );  
    }

})(file,loading); 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Read the image
$( '#clear, #result' ).show();
```

There are plenty of resources on SO you can read those for a better insight but in simple words closure will isolate all the values referenced in inner function **at a particular moment** store them somewhere safe and give them to functions when they're ready to run so even though identically named variables would get assinged some different value they don't affect those sandboxed in closure

Regarding css , i know very little on that you may try something like `margin`,`margin-left` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked great, I adjusted the css a little and now everything is just right.  Cheers.

Comment: You got it ! :)